# Overwrite attributes from DOT file in commandline with graphviz

Tags: graphviz, dot

I have graphviz installed on a linux VM. I am automatically converting .apt into .dot files using APT. I draw these with graphviz and the dot command. But it keeps showing the xlabels, which are set automatically by APT. Is there a way to surpress these xlabels, so they dont show ?

-Gforcelabels=false didn't work and i could not change the labels with -Exlabel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**dot -Nxlabel="" -Exlabel="" -T...**  should(?) work, but it does not!  I consider this a bug, not a feature.
This does work:

```
gvpr -c 'E{$.xlabel=""}N{$.xlabel=""}' file.dot |dot -Tsvg  >file.svg
```